# Using variable names to instantiate a class

Tags: php, oop, class, controllers

I'm trying to do something like this:

`$controller = new $controller . 'Controller';`

Which would create a new instance of the `PagesController` class if `$controller` was `Pages`. I'm getting this error, however:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Pages' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\application\app.php on line 25
```

The class is named `PagesController`.

I've seen this done in PHP before, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this

```
$controller = $controller . 'Controller';
$controller = new $controller();
```

Comment: Same error as above: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class PagesController could not be converted to string`

Comment: This is the proper way on how to do it. What line is it giving the error on? Are you doing anything in your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$controller .= 'Controller';
$controller = new $controller();
```

Documentation:
[Constructors and Destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)
[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: The first method results in a syntax error but the second method produces this error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class PagesController could not be converted to string`.

Comment: Does this error happen on the line where you wrote `$controller = new $controller;`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a different line to check for errors where I was `die()`'ing `$controller`. This solution works after all, although Kris posted it a few minutes before you so I'll accept his answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will only work if you specify the full namespace regardless whether you used `use` or `namespace` before.

```
use \App\Article\Health as Health;

$article = new Health; // works fine

$classname = "Health";
$article = new $classname(); // Class 'Health' not found.

$c = "\\App\\Article\\$classname";
$article = new $c(); // works fine
```